# SurfaceView crashes on close

Tags: android, crash, surfaceview

My custom SurfaceView class crashes when i try to end the application. When pressing "home" or "back" the application will end, but notifying me: "'game' has crashed"

how do i end a surfaceview properly?

Thanks in advance

logcat:

```
02-12 23:51:07.661: D/OpenGLRenderer(32561): Enabling debug mode 0
02-12 23:51:09.450: W/dalvikvm(32561): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41eaeb90)
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1321
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561): Process: com.ochs.x, PID: 32561
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561):    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:343)
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14436)
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561):    at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:334)
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561):    at com.ochs.x.GameView.draw(GameView.java:109)
02-12 23:51:09.450: E/AndroidRuntime(32561):    at com.ochs.x.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:25)
02-12 23:51:09.575: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32561): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

And this is my drawing method:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(30);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("mX: " + mx, 10, 30, textPaint);
    canvas.drawText("mY: " + my, 10, 70, textPaint);
    canvas.drawText("calX: " + calibrationX, 10, 110, textPaint);
    canvas.drawText("calY: " + calibrationY, 10, 150, textPaint);

}
```

I already had the same problem some months ago but I forgot how to properly close an activity containing a custom surfaceview...

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: added logcat to the question

Comment: You have a null pointer exception in the draw method of your GameView class, could you post that code? You might have cleaned up some objects but still trying to draw them.

Comment: Added the draw method to the question... how do i properly shut down a surfaceview?